# Meteor: Verify shopify webhook

Tags: meteor, shopify, webhooks, hmac

I am trying to verify webhook requests to be originated from shopify. For that I have referred: [verify shopify webhook](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/webhooks#verify-webhook)
. I have created an shopify app and since I am auto registering(creating) web-hooks to associated store so using app secret to verify the same.

The code is:

```
import { Picker } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';

var bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' ),
    crypto     = require('crypto');

Picker.middleware( bodyParser.json() );
Picker.middleware( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) );

var post = Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
  // Bypass, if the url doesn't start with webhook 
  if (req.url.search('webhook') < 0) {
   return true;
  }

  let isValid = isValidWebhook(req);
  console.log( (isValid ? 'Verified' : 'Unverified') + ' webhook');

  return (isValid && req.method == "POST");
});

isValidWebhook = function (req) {
  const data       = JSON.stringify(req.body);  
  const header     = req.headers;
  const hmac       = header['x-shopify-hmac-sha256'];
  const appSecret  = Meteor.settings.shopify.secret;

  const calHmac  = crypto.createHmac("sha256", appSecret).update(data).digest("base64");

  return (hmac == calHmac);
}
```

Server side routing is being captured by [Picker](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker).
I am unable to verify it so far so any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with `const data = req.body` instead of `const data = JSON.stringify(req.body);` and let us know.

Comment: @HymnZ  Already tried, so once running code for calHmac, it throws an error "TypeError: Not a string or buffer"

Comment: In that case, try `const data = JSON.stringify(req.body)` and `const calHmac  = crypto.createHmac("sha256", appSecret).update(data,'utf8').digest("base64");`

Comment: Tried, still unverified.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct secret; there are two. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763029/1455074

Comment: Thank you for your insight. But once I switched from meteor to node. It worked with no issues. The only conclusion that I came up with, was that, the package Picker was making some changes to the posted data.