# Verify Shopify webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-post, shopify, webhooks

I believe that to have a Shopify webhook integrate with a Rails app, the Rails app [needs to disable the default `verify_authenticity_token` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3041), and implement its own authentication using the `X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256` header. The [Shopify docs](https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/webhooks#verify-webhook) say to just use `request.body.read`. So, I did that:

```
def create
    verify_webhook(request)

    # Send back a 200 OK response
    head :ok
end

def verify_webhook(request)
    header_hmac = request.headers["HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256"]
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256")
    request.body.rewind
    calculated_hmac = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, SHARED_SECRET, request.body.read)).strip

    puts "header hmac: #{header_hmac}"
    puts "calculated hmac: #{calculated_hmac}"

    puts "Verified:#{ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(calculated_hmac, header_hmac)}"
end
```

The Shopify webhook is directed to the correct URL and the route gives it to the controller method shown above. But when I send a test notification, the output is not right. The two HMACs are not equal, and so it is not verified. I am fairly sure that the problem is that Shopify is using the entire request as their seed for the authentication hash, not just the POST contents. So, I need the original, untouched HTTP request, unless I am mistaken.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850256/how-do-i-see-the-whole-http-request-in-rails) question seemed like the only promising thing on the Internet after at least an hour of searching. It was exactly what I was asking and it had an accepted answer with 30 upvotes. But his answer... is absurd. It spits out an unintelligible, garbled mess of all kinds of things. Am I missing something glaring?

Furthermore, [this article](http://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/examining-internals-of-rails-request-response-cycle/) seemed to suggest that what I am looking for is not possible. It seems that Rails is never given the unadulterated request, but it is split into disparate parts by Rack, before it ever gets to Rails. If so, I guess I could maybe attempt to reassemble it, but I would have to even get the order of the headers correct for a hash to work, so I can't imagine that would be possible.

I guess my main question is, am I totally screwed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in my SHARED_SECRET. I assumed this was the API secret key, because a few days ago it was called the shared secret in the Shopify admin page. But now I see a tiny paragraph at the bottom of the notifications page that says,

> All your webhooks will be signed with ---MY_REAL_SHARED_SECRET--- so
>   you can verify their integrity.

This is the secret I need to use to verify the webhooks. Why there are two of them, I have no idea.

Comment: Hey im having the same issue, where did you get this other key? I'm creating a public app not just sending a single stored webhook, is this what you were doing?

Comment: I was creating a public app and building a webhook. I was confusing the API key for the app with the shared secret for the webhook. The API key is in the Shopify admin page I believe, and the webhook secret is at the bottom of the notifications page. At least, this was true 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it in the order they show in their guides? They have a working sample for ruby.

```
def create
  request.body.rewind
  data = request.body.read
  header = request.headers["HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256"]
  verified = verify_webhook(data, header)

  head :ok
end
```

They say in their guides:

> Each Webhook request includes a X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256 header which is
>   generated using the app's shared secret, along with the data sent in
>   the request.

the keywors being "generated using shared secret AND DATA sent in the request" so all of this should be available on your end, both the DATA and the shared secret.

Comment: The order in which I wrote it should not matter, but I tried the exact order of the guide anyway, and it still did not work. The word "data" seems to suggest it is just the request body, but the fact remains that my code is not producing the same hash as them. That is why I assumed it meant the entire original request, including headers.

Comment: @tschwab, have you tried with just .body instead of .body.read?

Comment: Also, once, when encoding into base64, I had to .gsub("\n", '') the contents prior to encoding. Try also with strip inside, and without strip?

Comment: `body` returns an input stream, and `body.read` returns the body contents in a string, so it is definitely `body.read`. I tried without the strip, strip inside, strip inside AND outside, gsub() on the contents, gsub without strip, and a few others. None of it worked. I just worked up a systematic way of testing every possibility, so I will continue trying iterations. Could it possibly be a version difference problem in OpenSSL?

Comment: @tschwab - I don't think so but you could try to update the gem. Also, it seems you don't need .body.rewind in Rails >= 3, that's specifically for sinatra. And, although this shouldn't be the problem: OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256") - try with OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha256')

Comment: I've tried the single quotes too, but nothing. My gems are updated, but I thought it might be possible that Shopify's were not when they wrote the guide. I went through the several hundred iterations of `strip` and `gsub` at each step of the process, and none of them worked. I am going to ask the Shopify team directly. I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: @tschwab -> not single quotes but: OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new.... with digest submodule added - it prolly calls super, so shouldnt be that, but you never know lol

Comment: Ah. I did that at first, but ruby complained that it was deprecated. But I tried it again, and still nothing.